# How to use PC mic to trigger android google

Tags: tasker, google-now, microphone

I have setup many tasker profiles and tasks etc. with AutoVoice to trigger with Google Now. I have recently acquired a wireless headset and I feel it would be more pratical if I could use the mic in the headset rather than my phone's microphone. Is there any way I could achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to use your PC's mic or your wireless headset to trigger Google Now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the headset is connected to the computer only, then this can't be done solely via Tasker. You could have a computer program that listens on the headset and sends some type of trigger (SMS, PushBullet, etc.) or an entire command to your phone. Tasker could then detect this trigger and open voice command (though it would be listening via the phone mic) or, if the program sent the entire command, Tasker could then be used to process this command.